# итератор цикла for как переменная

Tags: python, for, exif

Пишу небольшую програмку для роботы с EXIF данными(метаданными)
Дошел к этапу где нужно красиво вывести все метки

```
filename = input("->")
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    file = Image(file)
    if file.has_exif == True:
        print(Align("Succes! EXIF data finded!", style="green"))
        file_exif_data = file.list_all()
        for i in file_exif_data:
            print(i + file.i)
```

Но библиотека ищет значение `i` в метаданных, а не использует переменную:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\exif\_app1_metadata.py", line 591, in __getattr__
    attribute_id = ATTRIBUTE_ID_MAP[item.lower()]
KeyError: 'i'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\all\failes\scripts\exiff\main.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(file.i)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\exif\_image.py", line 104, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._segments["APP1"], item)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\exif\_app1_metadata.py", line 593, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"unknown image attribute {item}")
AttributeError: unknown image attribute i
```

Comment: не понятно, про какую переменную вы говорите, потому что, очевидно, file.list_all() - это и есть метаданные. вообще, все придумано до вас: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image - смотрите ответ про третий питон.

Comment: Что такое `file.i`, почему так должно работать? Хотя бы `file[i]` я бы ещё понял, да и то нужно смотреть, что вы такое вообще перебираете.